# BeautifulSoup treating '<' '>' html tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a string which is in unicode. In the string, I am replacing the '\r' character with '<\p>' in the string, and passing that to BeautifulSoup for parsing.

If I print after the string after the replacement, I see that the replacement went fine.
But when I pass the string to BeautifulSoup it treats it like < and >. Why is that ?

I seems to have to do with encoding, but not sure what.

replacing the string

```
fileString.encode('utf-8')  
fileString = re.sub('\r', "/<\p>", fileString)  
fileString.encode('utf-8')

htmlTag = BeautifulSoup(fileString, from_encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: The content that I want to capture ends where '\r' line character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<\p>` isn't a closing tag. The slash goes the other way:

```
fileString = fileString.replace('\r', '</p>')
```